# Convert visual studio install project to WIX

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, wix, windows-installer

I was wondering if anyone knows how easy it would be to convert an install project created with the standard visual studio 2010 install project to a WIX project.

This install project has a custom actions dll as well. I read about Heat but I'm not sure what it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd describe the process more as refactoring then converting.  For example, the custom actions you are using very well may not be needed.  Often times CA's are used to do things that MSI supports natively such as installing a windows service. (Reinventing the wheel.)

I approach situations like this with:

1) Examine the VDPROJ and custom actions for intent.

2) Possibly use Dark to decompile the MSI to wxs files.

3) Reauthor the WiX as cleanly as possible.

I've done this many times so it's 'easy' for me.  If you don't have the underlying Windows Installer experience and/or WiX experience, it'll be far more difficult yet also rewarding in terms of building your skillset.

Comment: I didn't know about Dark, thanks! that seems like a good place to start.

The custom action is quite straight forwards, it's just to set some env variables and remove them when the application gets removed. It also removes any new generated files in the install folder which prevents the uninstaller from deleting the folder on.

Comment: Then the custom actions aren't needed. MSI exposes these capabilities through the Environment table and the RemoveFile table.